# Discord python on role grant event

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord, discord.py

So i've been trying to get the bot to announce whenever a member gets a role granted, i know that this code may not make sense at all, but that's why i'm asking: How could i do it?

```
@bot.event
async def on_member_update(before, after):
    if str(after.roles) == 'android':
        fmt = "{0.mention} your role request has been accepted! :confetti_ball: You've been granted the role '{1}'"
        await bot.send_message(bot.get_channel('495285593711050754'), fmt.format(member, after.roles.name))
        print(colored('moderation.clf: ', 'blue'), colored('Android granted', 'white'))

    if str(after.roles) == 'human':
        fmt = "{0.mention} your role request has been accepted! :confetti_ball: You've been granted the role '{1}'"
        await bot.send_message(bot.get_channel('495285593711050754'), fmt.format(member, after.roles.name))
        print(colored('moderation.clf: ', 'blue'), colored('Human granted', 'white'))

    if str(after.roles) == 'moderator':
        fmt = "{0.mention} you are now part of the CyberLife staff, we're so excited to have you here! :confetti_ball:"
        await bot.send_message(bot.get_channel('495285593711050754'), fmt.format(member, after.roles.name))
        print(colored('moderation.clf: ', 'blue'), colored('Moderator granted', 'white'))
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First you have to check that the user got a new role.  Then you can check that the role they got is one of the ones you're looking for:

```
@bot.event
async def on_member_update(before, after):
    if len(before.roles) < len(after.roles):
        new_role = next(role for role in after.roles if role not in before.roles)
        if new_role.name in ('android', 'human'):
            fmt = "{0.mention} your role request has been accepted! :confetti_ball: You've been granted the role '{1}'"
            await bot.send_message(bot.get_channel('495285593711050754'), fmt.format(after, new_role.name))
        elif new_role.name in ('moderator'):
            fmt = "{0.mention} you are now part of the CyberLife staff, we're so excited to have you here! :confetti_ball:"
            await bot.send_message(bot.get_channel('495285593711050754'), fmt.format(after))
```

Comment: Seems to work, however `await bot.send_message(bot.get_channel('495285593711050754'), fmt.format(member))
NameError: name 'member' is not defined` shows up

Comment: `member` should be `after` there, my bad.

Comment: huge THANKS! Twice in a row, haha. Sorry for the bothers with my stupid questions