# on_member_update getting role added/removed's name

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord.py

So I am trying to make a log system but I can't seem to get the role name that is updated. How would I go about doing that?

```
    async def on_member_update(self, before, after):
    if before.nick != after.nick:
        cc = self.bot.get_channel(497404990076485663)
        ccc = discord.Embed(title=' ', description=f'{before.mention} **has changed their nickname from** `{before.nick}` **to** `{after.nick}`', color=0x00aad4)
        ccc.timestamp = datetime.datetime.utcnow()
        await cc.send(embed=ccc)
    elif before.roles != after.roles:
        cc = self.bot.get_channel(497404990076485663)
        csc = discord.Embed(title=' ', description=f"**{before.mention}'s role has been changed. Role add/removed:** {after.roles.name}", color=0x00aad4)
        csc.timestamp = datetime.datetime.utcnow()
        await cc.send(embed=csc)
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Discord python on role grant event](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53289546/discord-python-on-role-grant-event)

Comment: The difference here is that instead of `role for role in after.roles if role not in before.roles`  you would want `role for role in longer if role not in shorter`, where `shorter, longer = sorted([after.roles, before.roles], key=len)`